# How to close a command window after batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have a batch process in Win 8 that  changes to a directory, runs MS Access to produce a text file ( that’s HTML with data, thought that fun), then starts an FTP process  calling a text file that manages the upload. At the end of this I’m stuck with an open command window.
I’ve tried using “start” to start the ftp process, and I’ve played with using “exit” on the last line or not. Nothing is closing that window.

The File reads something like:

```
Cd\data
“c:\program files\office\msaccess” “c:\art\make_html_and_exit.mdb”
start ftp ftp.txt 
exit
```

The window stays open.
As this must happen 4 times a day, I worry I'll annoy the user at the desk having to close the command window so often.

Yes, I know that this question has been covered before, but I can't get the window to close.

Answer (score 2):

It is your "ftp-window" which is not closing. Right?
What are the contents of ftp.txt? The last line should be `quit`

By the way:
you should call ftp with

```
start ftp /s:ftp.txt
```

(see `ftp /?`)

Comment: *‘The last line should be `quit`’* – or `bye`

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have been  caused by  Logmein.  When I was at the client’s site, the batch window closed fully. I then logged in remotely from a machine on the next desk and found the same failure to close.